# Java Integer class code not compiling

Tags: java, integer, wrapper

I am new to Java.
I am Learning Wrapper class now from Online Resources
The following code does not compile but according to the online material this is giving results

```
class  Integ
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Integer I=new Integer.valueOf("1111",2);
        System.out.println(I);
    }
}
```

Can you please correct me where i am going wrong.

Comment: "The following code does not compile" - so what exact error does it give, on what line?

Comment: `Integer I = Integer.valueOf("1111", 2);` ... get rid of that rogue `new` keyword

Comment: [Your code is fine](http://rextester.com/VBP39513), minus that typo.

Comment: `new` operator expects constructor like `new Integer(...)`, not already existing object which will be returned via `Integer.valueOf(...)`. What is the point of using it here?

Comment: By the way… (a) This is not really a Wrapper class yet. It is just a place to stash a `main` method.  (b) In Java, variables hava a name starting with a lowercase letter. So `i` rather than `I`.

Answer (score 2):

```
class  Integ
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer i = Integer.valueOf("1111", 2);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use the new operator, just do `Integer.valueOf("1111",2);`

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Integer myI = new Integer.valueOf("1111",2);
               // ^^^
    System.out.println(I);
}
```

do instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Integer myI = Integer.valueOf("1111",2);
               // ^^^
    System.out.println(I);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to use `new`. Just remove it:

```
Integer I = Integer.valueOf("1111",2);
```